# Entity Framework 'An item cannot be removed from a fixed size Array of type *[]'

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, entity-framework

I am using EntityFramework to persist my entities.

The problem I have is that when sending an entity constructed in Silverlight over a WCF to be peristed I get the error 'An item cannot be removed from a fixed size Array of type 'CarterShop.Commerce.Entities.ManufacturedItemRequirement[]'.

I am inserting an entity (ManufacturedItem) which has an ICollection of ManufacturedItemRequirements. Entity Framework should allow me to just 'Add' this to the DbContext as a POCO object and persist this away, but for some reason it complains about the collection.

Has anyone hit this problem before? Basically I do not know what it is complaining about. The error comes from inside System.Data:

```
at System.Data.Objects.Internal.PocoPropertyAccessorStrategy.CollectionRemove(RelatedEnd relatedEnd, Object value)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapper`1.CollectionRemove(RelatedEnd relatedEnd, Object value)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.RemoveFromObjectCache(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DegradePromotedRelationships()
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.AddRelatedEntitiesToObjectStateManager(Boolean doAttach)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AddObject(String entitySetName, Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.<Add>b__4()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at Commerce.Model.Repositories.RepositoryBase`1.Add(T entity) in C:\OclProjects 4.1\CarterShop\CarterShop.Commerce.Model\Repositories\RepositoryBase.cs:line 28
   at CarterShop.Commerce.Services.Implementation.StockItemService.CreateManufacturedItem(ManufacturedItem manufactedItem, Boolean createDefinitionAswell) in C:\OclProjects 4.1\CarterShop\CarterShop.Commerce.Services\Implementation\StockItemService.cs:line 137
```

I am basically doing:

```
ManufacturedItem item = new ManufacturedItem();
item.ManufacturedItemRequirements.Add(new ManufacturedItemRequirement() { Quantity = 1; DefinitionId = 5 });

// Send to WCF...

Context.ManufacturedItems.Add(item); // Error thrown here.
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Is the item you're adding involved in a relationship with another item ? It look like the add implies a remove from another collection.

Comment: It should be a brand new item.. Added description.

Comment: What type is a collection of item's `ManufactureItemRequirement` after deserializaton on the server side?

Comment: It is an Array, which is why things cannot be removed from it, its read only. But I dont see why EF is trying to remove it? If only I could breakpoint System.Data.Objects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  was inserting the following graph:

```
ManufacturedItem has many ManufacturedItemRequirements.
ManufacturedItemRequirement has a ManufacturedItem.
ManufacturedItemRequirement has a StockItemDefinition.
```

This was being satisfied. However I was over looking one part of the graph which is:

```
StockItemDefinition has many ManufacturedItemRequirements.
```

Because I was not populating this reference array with the new ManufacturedItemRequirement, it would not work.

I do think I should not have to specify this, as that relationship is an implicit rather than explicit relationship. I think rather than generating an empty array for these properties it should generate NULL. If I set the child array to NULL the Add operation works.

I will let you know if I manage to change the way it is serialized.

Comment: I moved back to self tracking entities to get away from all this. I think the POCO objects are just not worth the hassle, especially now I've tried both.

Answer (score 6):

There are other situations where you will encounter this error, including when deleting entities that were obtained via use of the `.Include` extension methods.

The key is that if the relationship is defined as an `ICollection<T>` then Entity Framework will materialize the relationship by using an array.  However, there are many valid types you can choose from for relationships, including the types `ISet<T>` and `IList<T>`.  Using either of these to define your relationships will solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if your answer solves the original question but it helped me on a similar error triggered when using the DbSet.Local collection.

Comment: Why do arrays interface with ICollection, even thought it doesn't support remove()?

Comment: @Worthy7 I'm not sure I follow your question.  `[]` syntax applies to any collection type that implements a `this[...]` indexer.  Perhaps you should ask a new SO question?

Answer (score 3):

the cause of this is that the default EF classes created are treated as HashSet and the relationship is denoted as of type ICollection. If you open your generated class in the constructor, for the related object list, append a ToList() method like so:
    public ResultSet()
        {
            this.Results = new HashSet().ToList(); // added the ToList()
            .....
         }

then somewhere below you will see where its defined as a public virtual property like so:
    public virtual ICollection Results { get; set; }
Change from ICollection to List

...this solved the similar problem i was having... however you must take note that your code will be overwritten if you re-generate the class/model from database

Answer (score 0):

For multiply to multiply entity association mapping:

```
item *>|------|<* ManufacturedItemRequirement
```

Then there will be navigation property created both in item entity and ManufacturedItemRequirement named as item.ManufacturedItemRequirements and ManufacturedItemRequirement.items.

The new created ManufacturedItemRequirement should be insert to the entity table first to get a ID

```
var mf = new ManufacturedItemRequirement() { Quantity = 1; DefinitionId = 5 };
Context.ManufacturedItemRequirement.Add(mf);
Context.SaveChanges();
//then add the association to item
item.ManufacturedItemRequirements.Add(mf);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

If you check the database structure there will be a ID mapping table created for record the relationship between the Items and the ManufacturedItemRequirements. The Id of a entity object is required to establish the association.